# Difference between research statement and proposal?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, research-proposal, research-statement

I am going to apply for a research grant as a postdoc in mathematics. I would like to know is there any difference between `proposal` and `research statement` in the field of mathematics?

Comment: This is really a duplicate but I think [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/57116/75368) is most relevant.

Comment: Note that I've just updated the tag descriptions (wiki) for both of the tags. Perhaps that will make it more clear.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you for your comment